# SQLite error with ogr2ogr

Tags: ogr2ogr, ubuntu, sqlite

I'm trying to extract centroids from polygons.
I have already done it on Linux Fedora, MAC OS-X shell. The result was good.

Now I need to run the same command on UBUNTU shell, but it returns the following error:

ogr2ogr -dsco "SPATIALITE=YES" -sql "SELECT ST_Centroid(geometry), * FROM poly" -dialect sqlite centroids.shp filtered_result.shp

**Warning 6: driver ESRI Shapefile does not support creation option SPATIALITE
ERROR 6: The SQLite driver needs to be compiled to support the SQLite SQL dialect**

I have already installed SQlite as following:

- wget Page on sqlite.org
- tar xvfz sqlite-autoconf-3190200.tar.gz
- cd sqlite-autoconf-3190200
- ./configure
- make
- make install

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: Shapefile driver does not support anything like -dsco spatialite=yes. Take it out. The other problem is that you must first compile SQLite and Spatialite and then GDAL with those two if you want to use ST_Centroid.